# How to replace value in a column where a condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas dataframe, I would need to replace all the values 1990.0 with 2002.0 when User is Lucas:

```
User        Val
Mirk        1992.0
Lucas       1990.0
John        1980.0
Lucas       1990.0
Mirk        1992.0
```

Expected output:

```
User        Val
Mirk        1992.0
Lucas       2002.0
John        1980.0
Lucas       2002.0
Mirk        1992.0
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Your expected output seems to have first `1992` corresponding to `Mirk` changed as well.

Comment: sorry my fault. I am fixing it. Thanks for the spot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df.User.eq('Lucas') & df.Val.eq(1990), 'Val'] += 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use where from Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
df['Val'] = np.where((df['User'] == 'Lucas') & (df['Val'] == 1990), 2002, df['Val'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `mask`

```
df.Val.mask(df.User.eq('Lucas') & df.Val.eq(1990),2002,inplace=True)
```